# 'pimcore.registerNS is not a function' in admin after fresh pimcore installation

Tags: pimcore

Fresh Pimcore installation. Front end works fine, but the admin page is blank and I see some errors in browser console:

```
startup.js?_dc=4104:748 Uncaught TypeError: pimcore.registerNS is not a function
at startup.js?_dc=4104:748
```

I have installed my copy of pimcore followed the instructions: https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-pimcore-cms-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I use Ubuntu 16.04 / PHP 7.0.22 / Nginx 1.10.3 / Pimcore 4.6.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: I gave up and intalled the latest version of pimcore and everything works fine :)
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

That most certainly means that one of the JSON responses has an uncaught Exception message in there. Open developer tools and check all responses under Network and look for any weird error messages in there.

Comment: Thanks Igor. Unfortunately every status is 200.

Comment: Also check out the source code of the main page (richt click + show source code). Look in there for any error.

Comment: Good clue. One of script is empty: /admin/misc/script-proxy?scripts=minified_javascript_core_ebb178ae2a75395273e5de4dc92a611f.js&_dc=4104". Should it be generated in any way?

Comment: I think that should not be empty. I would try fixing all the file rights and clearing the cache.

Comment: It is not a rights problem. For test I set 777 for all directors and files an cleared the cache and the same problem did not disappear.

Comment: Please check the logs in /website/var/log - debug.log and php.log.

Comment: Both log files shows nothing special. I checked them using tail and there are no any new log during refresh the invalid page :(

Comment: I get many javascript console errors after an install. It begins with:
uncaught TypeError: pimcore.registerNS is not a function

Comment: pimcore.registerNS not being a function is for some reason, an namespace.js file not being either included or executed. No idea as to why since everything is right where it should be in terms of a none working and a working installation (both were previously working).

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the cache and it worked.

Execute this command in the CLI:

```
php pimcore/cli/console.php cache:clear
```